# Use column of join in where condition

Tags: nhibernate, join, hql, left-join, where-clause

I do the fallowing HQL with NHibernate:

```
from Contact a where IsInternal = 0
```

this give me the fallowing sql (from NHProfiler):

```
select TOP ( 25 /* @p0 */ ) contact0_.Id                   as Id29_,
                   contact0_.ObjectVersion        as ObjectVe2_29_,
                   ...
                   ...
from   Contact contact0_
       left outer join Company contact0_1_
         on contact0_.Id = contact0_1_.Id
       left outer join Person contact0_2_
         on contact0_.Id = contact0_2_.Id
       left outer join Branch contact0_3_
         on contact0_.Id = contact0_3_.Id
       left outer join ContactGroup contact0_4_
         on contact0_.Id = contact0_4_.Id
where  contact0_.IsInternal = 0
```

I want now extend the where-condition with

```
   ... and (contact0_1.Id is not null or contact0_2_.Id is not null)
```

The question is now, how can I access the joined table in the HQL?

Best Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er, if the field is null, then referenced object is null. So:

`where IsInternal = 0 and (a.person is not null or a.company is not null)`